# How to use a macro for the list of optional arguments to another macro?

Tags: macros, fancyvrb

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\def\p{fontsize=\small}
\VerbatimInput[\p]{a.txt}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't compile. What is the right way to use `\p` as an optional argument?

Comment: really you should not get in the position of needing this, but `\expandafter\VerbatimInput\expandafter[\p]{a.txt}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle please, post it as an answer, I will accept it (btw, what is the reason of posting a comment, if it's an answer? :)

Comment: people copy code from answers and I'd rather they didn't copy that, if you gave some more context the right answer is probably to not use `\p` and set the `fontsize` key instead

Comment: If you want to setup a style, it would make more sense to define a new key, e.g. `\define@key{FV}{mystyle}[]{\setkeys{FV}{fontsize=\small}}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer no harm here, as the nested `\setkeys` uses the same set, but in general, nesting `\setkeys` is problematic.

Comment: @Skillmon How about `\define@key{FV}{mystyle}[\small]{\KV@FV@fontsize{#1}}`?

Comment: @UlrichDiez would be fine, the issue is that `\setkeys` doesn't "remember" the set in use outside of the current call, hence a nested call can affect the outer call of it. That's not the case in Ulrike's comment (and I'm sure she knows this), but since you generally can't nest it, I tend to leave a note about this for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a wrapper for calling `\expanded` after adjusting LaTeX's expansion-protection/prevention-mechanism:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\expandstuff[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\protect=\@unexpandable@protect
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expanded{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\p{fonts\q}\def\q{ize=\small}

\expandstuff{\protect\VerbatimInput[\p]}{a.txt}

\end{document}
```